# Disable main browser, display popup with window.open and do some actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using ajax for some function for my website, in success function I write some code:

```
success: function(html) {
     window.open("http://localhost/demo/index.php",'name','height=243,width=800');
}
```

There are some problems I met:

1. This page (popup window) can not load css
2. I can disable main browser
3. I want to redirect main window after popup window is closed

How can I do that?

**P/S: If I can't do that, how do I display popup when success function is called?**

Comment: what do you mean by "popup can not load css" ?

Comment: it means that that page can not styled :(

Comment: It might be due to incorrect URL's. Did you try checking for any loading errors?

Comment: If I can't do that, how do I display popup when success function is called?

Comment: No i mean, CSS link URL's from within pop-up

Answer (score 2):

**1. This page (popup window) can not load css**
There might be some problem with your style urls. Check them in browser console.

**2. I can disable main browser**
You can't disable main browser, but As per my understanding you are trying to block page elements. So [block UI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) can help. Use block UI to block your page contents and it will be automatically removed when you will redirect your main page.

**3. I want to redirect main window after popup window is closed**

You need to bind a custom redirect method to your window close to redirect your main page when window is closed.

```
success: function (html) {
    myWindow = window.open("http://localhost/demo/index.php", 'name', 'height=243,width=800');
    myWindow.onbeforeunload = function () {
            return RedirectPage();
}
function RedirectPage() {
    window.location.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect main window using:

```
window.parent.location.href = "http://www.site.com";
```

Regarding popup window not loading css, it might be issue with improper CSS include URL's in popup page html.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Becase css's url is wrong, I fixed. If I can't do what I said, how do I display popup when success function is called?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. What do you mean by "If I can't do what I said" ?

Comment: What I said in #1 :) After success event in ajax, I want to show popup.Maybe popup windows or any other type popup.